# Rendering svg from flask in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, svg, flask, jinja2

I am scraping svg html code from a site. Now I want to render template with that code (which is stored in a variable in python). The svg code is the contribution chart of github from the url - github.com/username/contributions.

SVG code -

```
<svg>
.....
</svg>
```

I am not able to complete this task. How to pass the variable as parameter to the render_template() function? In some formats it is showing me the actual code, in others, it is not displaying a thing at all.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Flask uses the JINJA2 template engine, but the same applies to many template engines on many platforms.

**For security reasons**, any HTML data your code sends into a JINJA2 template will be *escaped* by default, i.e. `<svg>` will become `&lt;svg&gt;`. This is the reason why it is showing you the actual code in the browser.

JINJA2 allows you to *not escape HTML*, but this can be dangerous, especially if the code is provided by users. For example, some evil JavaScript could be injected into your pages. So you eventually need to protect your app and users from such attacks.

That said, one of the options to not escape HTML tags is use of the `safe` filter. For example:

```
<div>
{{ svgCode|safe }}
</div>
```

See JINJA2 docs for more information: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#html-escaping